# How to print numbers into a columnar structure onto a text file with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

This question is probably more related to my lack of imagination, but I have a relatively simple problem that I am trying to solve.  I am trying to write a function that will allow you to write an array or list of numbers to the terminal or to a text file with a columnar output and I am running up against a fundamental problem.  The method within my function is listed below.

```
j = 0
length = int(len(result)/4)
for i in range(length):
    print('{:6.4e}{}{:6.4e}{}{:6.4e}{}{:6.4e}'.format(result[j], ' ',
                                              result[j + 1], ' ',
                                              result[j + 2], ' ',
                                              result[j + 3]))
    j = j + 4
```

As you can see it is not a very elegant implementation and it runs into a problem.  Your output has to be an even multiple of 4 or it does not print the remaining numbers.  For instance, if the numbers are

```
np.array([0.0, 34.681, 54.281, 22.987, 101.785, 34.187, 101.16, 298.7, 
          39.841, 8.731])
```

The output should be

```
0.0000e+00 3.4681e+01 5.4281e+01 2.2987e+01
1.0179e+02 3.4187e+01 1.0160e+02 2.9870e+01
3.9841e+01 8.731e+01
```

but instead the output will be

```
0.0000e+00 3.4681e+01 5.4281e+01 2.2987e+01
1.0179e+02 3.4187e+01 1.0160e+02 2.9870e+01
```

So my first question is how doing I rewrite this print statement to handle the printing of the uneven rows?  Second, is there a more elegant way to re-write the print statement so I do not have to manually write the `'{:.64e}{}{:.64e}{}{:64e}{}{:.64e}'` statement, especially since I hope to make the number of columns a user input function to the function and don't want to manually write each possibility into a series of if statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind an extra (typically invisible) space at the end of each line:

```
NCOLS = 4 # Number of columns
SEP = " " # Column separator
for i,value in enumerate(result):
    print('{:6.4e}'.format(value), end=SEP)
    if i % NCOLS == NCOLS - 1: 
        print() # A line break
if i % NCOLS != NCOLS - 1: 
        print() # The final line break
```

Output:

```
0.0000e+00 3.4681e+01 5.4281e+01 2.2987e+01 
1.0179e+02 3.4187e+01 1.0160e+02 2.9870e+01 
3.9841e+01 8.7310e+01
```

Comment: @holdenweb Pardon me? This _exactly_ answers the OP's question.

Comment: Even with the numbers 3 and 4 it was directly answering the OPs question: "_Your output has to be an even multiple of 4_".

Comment: Clearly that was the OP describing the limitations of his solution that he wanted to overcome. Otherwise his given solution already works, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Variation on a theme:

```
a = np.array([0.0, 34.681, 54.281, 22.987, 101.785,
              34.187, 101.16, 298.7, 39.841, 8.731])

ncols = 4
nrows = (len(a) // ncols) + 1
s = '{:<12.4e}'    # two spaces separating the columns
for row in range(nrows):
    start = row * ncols
    group = slice(start, start + ncols)
    line = a[group]
    fmt = s * len(line)
    print(fmt.format(*line))
```

---

Relies on a slice with a stop value greater than the sequence length behaving properly - which it does.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to split a list into into groups of four is using slicing. If you then remove the elements after you processed them, iteration can stop when the list becomes empty (if you don't want to destroy the list you'll need to make a copy first). The advantage of slicing is that it handles the case where there aren't enough elements remaining for a full slice.

You will, however, have to use a printing technique that can accommodate any number of items from one to four.

```
while len(result):
    this_line = result[:4]
    result = result[4:]
    line = ["{:6.4e}".format(item) for item in this_line]
    print(" ".join(line))
```

If you build a function that works this way, you could replace the literal `4` with a parameter specifying the number of columns you wanted to print, and the code should still work.

Final note: Also, there's no need to insert spaces by substituting them. In your original attempt you could have put the spaces in the format string directly and written

```
    print('{:6.4e} {:6.4e} {:6.4e} {:6.4e}'.format(result[j],
                                              result[j + 1],
                                              result[j + 2],
                                              result[j + 3]))
```

If you didn't want to copy the list *or* destroy it, another possibility would be to maintain a sum of the lengths of the rows printed so far, and use `while length_sum < len(result)`.

Comment: Surely your solution is not general, either.

Comment: No, but I have (thanks to your comment) pointed out how it can be generalised. If you downvoted my answer because you are pissed at my downvote on yours I can live with it. Since your solution does (now) work in the general case I have removed the downvote, but the comments stand.

Comment: This solution as written does not work.  the `while result` line produces a value error, ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().  If you replace it with `while result.any()` the code works

Comment: Yeah, the question did say "array or list," didn't it? Drat!

Comment: Thanks. I'm somewhat off-colour today, and clearly would have been better off not posting - you were kind enough not to point out I was only printing 3 values per row! Anyway, now fixed so it does work for arrays too.